# Run a task asynchronously and when it finishes assign a class to a component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

Hello everyone. Sorry if this is a stupid question or something really easy. I'm new on the javascript scene and I'm trying to develop simple React application. It's just a basic loading animation made with HTML and CSS.

Until there everything works fine. The problem is how can I run a task asynchronously at the same time, and whenever the task finishes, make the loader stop?

I have a basic CSS class that makes the loader fade out, and I'd like to assign it to the loader when the task finishes.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

### Code:

**Loader component**

```
class Loader extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div class="sk-folding-cube">
            <div class="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Loader.css**

```
.sk-folding-cube {
width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
          transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FECB2F;
  -webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
          animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
          animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
          animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  } 25%, 75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  } 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  } 25%, 75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  } 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

**FadeOut Animation**

```
.completed {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeOutOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeOutOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the `<Loader />` conditionally in the parent component, based on state. Like `{ this.state.loading && <Loader /> }`. When the async operation finishes, call `this.setState({ loading: false });` That's the general mechanism. If you want to add a class instead, use `className={this.state.loading ? "" : "completed"}` or something like that.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks! This worked pretty well. Sorry for disturbing you, I'm new into this.